# Use of a function when importing a feed

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

I have a [Feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) which imports data from a CSV file. I import data of products, namely title, price, category, etc. However, in order to provide a friendly URL, I send a customized field, which is in different languages and completely verbose, for example: *Shoes for female scientists*. I want to use this description as part of the clean friendly URL, so I would need to use some function like `pathauto_cleanstring()`. However, the update takes ages to complete. Is there a faster way, for example directly on import?

This code is executed on a call to *mymodule_cronapi* via [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron), and through curl PHP function:

```
   $results = db_query('SELECT nid, title FROM node WHERE type= :product', array(":product" => "product") );
    foreach($results as $row){
        $node = node_load($row->nid);
        $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
        $node_wrapper->field_product_url->set(pathauto_cleanstring($row->title));
        $node_wrapper->save();
    } // foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Feeds Tamper to create your URLs based on values in your CSV: https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper

Comment: But I don't see nowhere in the GUI where I can choose *pathauto_cleanstring* or equivalent, which is what I need. URLencode or URLdecode won't do the trick, and the raw regular pattern probably won't either.